# Can rectifiable varifolds be thought of as generalized characteristic functions?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Consider an $n$-rectifiable varifold $V$, that is, a pair (or rather an equivalence class of pairs) $(M, θ)$ where $M$ is a countably $n$-rectifiable, $ℋ^n$-measurable subset of $ℝ^N$ and $θ$ is a positive and locally $ℋ^n$-integrable function on $M$. (All definitions as in [Leon Simon's 2014 notes on Geometric Measure Theory](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf).)

The associated Radon measure $μ_V$ is given by

$$
  μ_V(A) ≔ ∫_{M ∩ A} θ dℋ^n
$$

for all $ℋ^n$-measurable sets $A$. Consider the support of this measure:

$$
  \operatorname{supp}(μ_V) ≔ \{ x ∈ ℝ^N | ∀ \text{ open neighborhoods U of x: } μ_V(U) > 0 \}
$$

which is a closed set.

**Question:** (When) Do we have $\operatorname{supp}(μ_V) = M$ up to a set of $ℋ^n$-measure zero?

**Attempt at a proof:** By remark 1.8(2) and theorem 1.9 in Leon Simon's notes we have that the $n$-dimensional density $Θ^{*n}$ of $μ_V$ is:

$$
  Θ^{*n}(μ_V, x) = θ(x) > 0
$$

for $ℋ^n$-almost every $x ∈ M$. But by definition of the density this means that $ℋ^n$-almost every $x ∈ M$ has a neighborhood with positive $μ_V$-measure and therefore lies in $\operatorname{supp}(μ_V)$.

Conversely, let $x ∈ \operatorname{supp}(μ_V)$. Then by definition all balls centered at $x$ have non-zero $μ_V$ measure. But by definition of $μ_V$, this means that every ball centered at $x$ has to have non-empty intersection with $M$. Therefore, $\operatorname{supp}(μ_V)$ consists entirely of adherent points of $M$ and is therefore contained in the closure of $M$. It remains to show that $\operatorname{supp}(μ_V) ∖ M$ has vanishing measure. But here I'm not getting any further since, a priori, $\bar{M}∖M$ might easily have non-zero measure. (Consider that $ℝ$ is the closure of $ℚ$ and $ℝ∖ℚ$ has *full* measure.) I suppose I need to employ rectifiability of $M$ somehow.

Anyway, **suppose the proof can be done** and indeed $\operatorname{supp}(μ_V) = M$. But in this case we can forget about $M$ entirely: Set $\bar{θ} ≔ θ · χ_{\operatorname{supp}(μ_V)}$ where $χ_{\operatorname{supp}(μ_V)}$ is the characteristic function. Then we obviously have:

$$
  μ_V(A) = ∫_{M ∩ A} \bar{θ} dℋ^n = ∫_A \bar{θ} dℋ^n
$$

Since $θ$ was positive everywhere on $M = \operatorname{supp}(μ_V)$, we have $\operatorname{supp}(\bar{θ}) = \operatorname{supp}(μ_V) = M$. But the latter was $n$-rectifiable. So it seems that any varifold is given entirely in terms of a *non-negative* function $\bar{θ}$ whose support is $n$-rectifiable.

**Question 2:** Can $n$-rectifiable varifolds therefore be thought of generalizations of characteristic functions in the sense that they are given by non-negative functions (whose support is $n$-rectifiable)?

Comment: I am sorry for this vague comment, but let me toss in a couple key words: could "pure unrectifiability" be the answer to your first question? Like, use Federer's structure theorem to prove that the leftover must be purely unrectifiable, and since our whole space is rectifiable it must have measure zero. For question 2, my key word is "rectifiable measures." Rectifiable surfaces I would say are a subset of rectifiable measures. Again, this is only a vague comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! As for the first question: I don't think Federer's Structure Theorem helps: Since the set $M$ is already rectifiable it amounts to a tautology. Or at least I don't see how the purely unrectifiable set having measure zero would imply that $\operatorname{supp}(\mu_V) \setminus M$ has measure zero?

Comment: I was imagining that one might prove that $\text{supp}(\mu_V) \backslash M$ is purely rectifiable, and that $\text{supp}(\mu_V)$ itself is rectifiable. So, by structure theorem has no unrectifiable part of positive measure. Thus, forcing $\text{supp}(\mu_V) \backslash M$ to be of measure zero. Just thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

The support of a rectifiable measure could be the whole space. Take an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ and at each point $q_i\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ centre a segment of lenght $1/2^i$. This is a $1$ rectifiable set and which support is dense. I’d say that a good example of when the support is a good description of the geometry of the measure is when the its $n$-dimensional lower density is bounded away from $0$. Furthermore, keep in mind that the upper density is just a very weak information: the lower one is the real deal.

It’s not clear what Q2 means precisely, but my answer tends to be “yes. They are a way of making computations with rectifiable sets, but I prefer currents”.

EDIT: about the easy way of distinguishing when the support of $\mu_V$ has non-empty interior I do not have a really "always working idea". For general rectifiable sets you cannot expect any good behaviour in general.

If you prove that your set is contained in the complement of a cone, you can show it is a graph, for instance (chapter 15 of Mattila's book).

You can be sure that if the measure $\mu_V$ is such that $\mu_V(B(x,r))=h(r)$ for some increasing $h$ independent on $x$, then $supp(\mu_V)$ is an analytic manifold (Preiss-Kirchheim paper)

You could direcltly assume that $M$ is a closed set. Indeed, proofs don't care much about the support anyway since you can always restrict your computations to a compact set inside a borel set of the right dimension $supporting$ the measure and make the computations there.

Comment: That's a really neat example and it is providing me with more and more intuition the more I think about it! Thank you! Is there an easy way to see, though, that the difference between the support and your rectifiable set $M$, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus M$, has 1-dimensional measure $> 0$? (So that it is indeed a counterexample to my question 1?)

Comment: Speaking of question 1, is there any criterion to decide when the support $S$ of $\mu_V$ will agree (up to the symmetric difference having measure zero) with the rectifiable set $M$ we're taking the integral over? (So that, in particular, $S$ is rectifiable, too?) More generally, is there any criterion to decide when $S$ will be rectifiable itself (though not necessarily equal to $M$ up to a set of measure zero)?

Comment: As for question 2, it seems the answer is *no*, though, doesn't it? The support of the function $\bar{θ} = θ · χ_{\operatorname{supp}(μ_V)}$ is, by definition, the intersection of $\operatorname{supp}(θ) = \bar{M}$ and $\operatorname{supp}(μ_V) ≡ S$. But $S$ and $\bar{M}$ in your example are all of $ℝ^n$ and the latter doesn't look very $1$-rectifiable to me?

Comment: On a side note, I'm now realizing that I, at times, confused the support $S$ of the measure $\mu_V$ with the support of the function $θ$, which is the closure of $M$. But they are not at all the same (this is rather meant as a note to myself but please correct me if I'm wrong): …

Comment: … The support $S$ of the measure is necessarily contained in the closure $\bar{M} = \operatorname{supp}{θ}$ of the rectifiable set $M$ (because outside the closure one can always find open neighborhoods not intersecting $M$, so on these neighborhoods the integral will yield nothing). At the same time, $S$ might be strictly smaller than $\bar{M}$ and even than $M$, namely if $M$ contains "parts" of measure zero. (As an extreme example, the 1-rectifiable set $M = ℚ^n$ would yield $\bar{M} = \operatorname{supp}{θ} = ℝ^n$ but $S ≡ \operatorname{supp}(μ_V) = ∅$.)